# How to download a delayed file via HTTP in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, download, delay, open-uri

I use the following Ruby function to download various files via HTTP:

```
def http_download(uri, filename)
  bytes_total = nil
  begin
    uri.open(
      read_timeout: 500,
      content_length_proc: lambda { |content_length|
        bytes_total = content_length
      },
      progress_proc: lambda { |bytes_transferred|
        if bytes_total
          print("\r#{bytes_transferred} of #{bytes_total} bytes")
        else
          print("\r#{bytes_transferred} bytes (total size unknown)")
        end
      }
    ) do |file|
      open filename, 'w' do |io|
        file.each_line do |line|
          io.write line
        end
      end
    end
  rescue => e
    puts e
  end
end
```

I also want to download files ([csv](http://opendata.dc.gov/datasets/3e15a3bd2fd548b885a6fa5ac261ad29_4.csv), [kml](http://opendata.dc.gov/datasets/3e15a3bd2fd548b885a6fa5ac261ad29_4.kml), [zip](http://opendata.dc.gov/datasets/3e15a3bd2fd548b885a6fa5ac261ad29_4.zip), [geojson](http://opendata.dc.gov/datasets/3e15a3bd2fd548b885a6fa5ac261ad29_4.geojson)) from [this website](http://opendata.dc.gov/datasets/3e15a3bd2fd548b885a6fa5ac261ad29_4). However, there is **some kind of delay** set up. When I click the download link in the browser it takes a bit until the download window appears. I suppose the file needs to be processed on the server before it can be served.

How can I modify my script to take the delay into account?

I am running Ruby 2.2.2.

Comment: Hi, what's your Ruby version? I'm running your code using Ruby 2.2.2, got an exception of "private method 'open' called". And I've opened the website, is the "Download Dataset" button you click? I haven't run into the **delay** you mentioned, it's just the website url appends the `.csv`, `.kml`, `.zip` and several query params.

Comment: Yes, the latest version. Yes, the links are hidden under the "Download Dataset" button. Maybe, they buffer it on the server now that I clicked it. Try another dataset maybe.

Comment: I've found that, for a dataset the first time you request, it returns a JSON which represens the status, eg. `{ status: "processing", processing_time: 0, count: 0 }`,  `{ status: "processing", processing_time: 9.58, count: 0 }`. And after  processing, you'll download the file. So I think you may just add a judge and retry on the processing part.

Comment: Correct. What do you mean by adding a judge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the modification according to the post and comment:

```
require 'open-uri'

def http_download(uri, filename)
  bytes_total = nil
  index = 1
  begin
    open(
      uri,
      read_timeout: 500,
      content_length_proc: lambda { |content_length|
        bytes_total = content_length
      },
      progress_proc: lambda { |bytes_transferred|
        if bytes_total
          print("\r#{bytes_transferred} of #{bytes_total} bytes")
        else
          print("\r#{bytes_transferred} bytes (total size unknown)")
        end
      }
    ) do |io|
      # if "application/json" == io.content_type
      if io.is_a? StringIO
        raise " --> Failed, server is processing. Retry the request ##{index}"
      else # Tempfile
        puts "\n--> Succeed, writing to #{filename}"
        File.open(filename, 'w'){|wf| wf.write io.read}
      end
    end
  rescue => e
    puts e
    return if e.is_a? OpenURI::HTTPError # Processing error

    index += 1
    return if index > 10

    sleep index and retry
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome! One minor case I noticed is when the download is a JSON file - I added the link above.

Comment: Great! I tried the script on [another server](http://geoportaal.ddh.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/053dd72ba7c346be9c648210b6af2352_7) ([kml](http://geoportaal.ddh.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/053dd72ba7c346be9c648210b6af2352_7.kml)). For some reason it does not work there although it seems to be the same delay mechanism. Can you see the reason?

Comment: Sorry, I've made my work, and I don't think I can fix you all the cases.

Comment: Understood. Though it appears to me the same server installation. That's why it is strange data is not returned.